# Adding a prefix to value derived from sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have some JSON data, that due to a quirk on the system it's extracted from, posts two values for the same item. Eg:

```
[
   {
      "data":{
         "ecfa663b-3dd2-4aef-b25c-e43dd6b82enbRA004":"0001-01-01T00:00:00+00:00",
         "ecfa663b-3dd2-4aef-b25c-e43dd6b82enbRA013":"0001-01-01T00:00:00+00:00",
         "ecfa663b-3dd2-4aef-b25c-e43dd6b82enbMRA013":"2020-09-21T18:15:36.4919022+01:00",
         "ecfa663b-3dd2-4aef-b25c-e43dd6b82enbRA010":"2020-09-21T18:12:35.4119042+01:00",
         "ecfa663b-3dd2-4aef-b25c-e43dd6b82enbMRA004":"2020-09-21T00:00:00+01:00"
      },
      "columns":[
         {
            "name":"Assessment One",
            "keySegment":"RA004",
            "mandatory":"true"
         },
         {
            "name":"Assessment Two",
            "keySegment":"RA013",
            "mandatory":"true"
         },
         {
            "name":"Assessment Three",
            "keySegment":"RA010",
            "mandatory":"false"
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

RA004 and RA013 are correct, but they are classed as mandatory assessments by the software system and so an "M" prefix is added to the individual person's identifier (the longer number).

My (probably not very efficient) code for extracting this JSON into SQL Server is as follows:

```
    BEGIN TRY 
    SELECT      
        LEFT(x.[Key],36) AS "ConnectionID", 
        y.name AS "Assessment", left(x.[Value],19) as "ReviewDate" 
            
        INTO [AssessmentToolsStatus] 
    
        FROM OPENJSON(@JSON, '$[0].data') AS x
            
        CROSS APPLY
        OPENJSON(@JSON, '$[0].columns')
        WITH
        (
            name nvarchar(50) '$.name',
            keySegment nvarchar(10) '$.keySegment',
            mandatory nvarchar(10) '$.mandatory'
        ) y
    
        WHERE REPLACE(x.[Key], Left(x.[Key],36),'') = y.keySegment
```

However, I'm unsure how to account for the "MRA"s. I want something like "if keySegment in 'RA004', 'RA013') then keySegment = 'M' + keySegment", but I don't quite know how in SQL. I don't need the RA004, RA013 entries because the date stamps are meaningless.

Can anyone help?
Thanks

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (Perhaps MS SQLServer?)

Comment: Sorry!! Yes. SQLServer. I did add the tag but didn't mention it in the post. Corrected and sorry again.

Comment: I've added the sql-server tag for you ('sql' is a very general tag meaning that some version of sql is involved or possibly that it's a general q about sql and no particular version is implied)

Comment: Thanks. I do normally put sql-server but for some reason I missed off the server part...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, a possible solution is the below statement (I assume, that `RA004` and `RA013` are the items from the `$.columns` JSON array with `$.mandatory` equal to `"true"`):

```
SELECT      
   LEFT(x.[Key], 36) AS "ConnectionID", 
   y.name AS "Assessment", 
   LEFT(x.[Value], 19) AS "ReviewDate"
-- INTO [AssessmentToolsStatus]
FROM OPENJSON(@JSON, '$[0].data') AS x
JOIN OPENJSON(@JSON, '$[0].columns') WITH (
   name nvarchar(50) '$.name',
   keySegment nvarchar(10) '$.keySegment',
   mandatory nvarchar(10) '$.mandatory'
) y ON 
   STUFF(x.[key], 1, 36, '') = 
   CONCAT(CASE WHEN y.mandatory = 'true' THEN 'M' ELSE '' END, y.keySegment)
```

Result:

```
ConnectionID                         Assessment       ReviewDate
ecfa663b-3dd2-4aef-b25c-e43dd6b82enb Assessment One   2020-09-21T00:00:00
ecfa663b-3dd2-4aef-b25c-e43dd6b82enb Assessment Two   2020-09-21T18:15:36
ecfa663b-3dd2-4aef-b25c-e43dd6b82enb Assessment Three 2020-09-21T18:12:35
```