# Using SQL to judge in date, expiring soon and expired

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, case

Following on from a previous question I've asked about this data...

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63632634/adding-a-prefix-to-value-derived-from-sql/63633061#63633061)

I then have a table that gives me ConnectionID (and therefore the link to the Patients table, so I can extrapolate their name), Assessment name, and review date.

I have added an extra column called Update Status, which is designed to display

- "IN Date" if the review date is at least a week into the future
- "DUE Soon" if the review date is within the next 7 days from GetDate()
- "Expired" if the review date is the day before GetDate() (ie, yesterday), or earlier.

I have been looking so hard at this seemingly easy and obvious bit of logic programming, to the point where I'm getting a headache and could use a fresh pair of eyes. The relevant section of my query is:

```
SELECT <<<<<OTHER FIELDS>>>>>>,

CASE
    WHEN (GetDate() < cast(ats.ReviewDate as date)
    AND DATEDIFF(DAY,GetDate(), CAST(ats.ReviewDate AS DATE)) <1)           
            THEN ''IN Date''
    WHEN GetDate() > cast(ats.ReviewDate as date) then ''OUT of Date''
    WHEN DATEDIFF(day, cast(ats.ReviewDate as date),GetDate()+7 ) > 1 THEN ''DUE SOON''
    WHEN ats.ReviewDate  is NULL THEN ''Not Yet Reviewed'' END as [Update Status]
END
```

This is obviously incorrect, because items well in the future (ie 2020-09-21) are NULL, items due soon (ie 2020-08-30) are correctly saying "DUE Soon", and items in the past are correctly showing "OUT of Date".

I'm missing something obvious, but can't see it. Please help.

Comment: Your last datediff() is wrong, it would never be TRUE, try changing the place of arguments, GetDate()+7 should be first, otherwise it would be DUE SOON for past.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this do what you want?

```
case
    when ats.ReviewDate is null then 'Not yet reviewed'
    when ats.ReviewDate >= dateadd(week, 1, cast(getdate() as date)) then 'In date'
    when ats.ReviewDate >=  cast(getdate() as date) then 'Due Soon'
    else 'Expired'
end
```

The logic is as follows:

- "Not yet reviewed": review date is `null`
- "In Date": review date is at least 7 days after today at 00:00
- "Due Soon": review date is greater than today (and not more than 7 days later)
- "Expired": all other cases

Hint: `case` evaluates the branches sequentially, and stops at the first match (remaining branches are ignored); putting the branches in the optimal sequence often allows simplifying the logic and avoids repeating conditions across branches.